# wxmediactrl producing poor video quality

Tags: video, windows-7, media-player, wxwidgets

I have a few mpg videos which I need to analyse and be displayed in gui. The problem I have is that wxwidgets produce glitches while playing these videos.

wxwidgets use WMP of my system by default and when I load the same file using WMP itself, I don't get these glitches. I don't have these glitches when the file is loaded in OpenCV as well, only in wxwidgets. The results are the same using both, my produced code and sample mediaplayer code provided with the wxwidgets library.

Also, I tried opening the file of mp4 format and there were no glitches anymore.

The mpg file has: data rate - 1150kbps, total bitrate - 1406kbps and frame rate 25frames/second

Any insight on why this is happening would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did not get the answer, however managed to work around. In such case all you have to do is build your own media player using simple rendering instead of using pre-built media player and then there's no problem with glitches anymore given you give enough time for gui to draw the frame before proceeding to next one.

Thanks.